# Apply specific style to recursive angular element

Tags: css, angular, recursion

I am creating this recursive nested tree view component in Angular. Goal is that whenever a node is selected, styling should be applied to that node with .node-active class and when other node is selected the previous styling applied should be removed and should be added to current selected node. Its working fine for one sub-tree but when I select other node from other sub-tree the styling gets applied to other sub-tree also. Here is the stackblitz link - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-example-bx5mwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree%2Ftree.component.ts)

[image: tree-view component]

I am applying a class using applyStyle function based on the current node code and selected node code, which works for one sub-tree but breaks for another. Any help would be really helpful.

tree.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css'],
})
export class TreeComponent {
  @Input() tree: any;
  @Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public selectedItem: any;

  toggleChild(node) {
    this.selectedValue.emit(node);
    node.showChildren = !node.showChildren;
    node.isOpen = !node.isOpen;
  }

  /* Events are not bubbled up so emitting the parent event on <app-tree>
   * when one of the child emits an event - this will create a new EventEmitter per child.
   */
  emitOnChildClicked(node) {
    this.selectedValue.emit(node);
  }

  applyStyle(node) {
    console.log(node);
    this.selectedItem = node.code;
  }
}
```

tree.component.css

```
.open-btn {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.close-btn {
  left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.node-item {
  color: var(--lbl-color);
  padding: 3px;
}

.green {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.node-active {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #379df1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.node-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  color: #0f0f0f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.arrow-btn {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.tree li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
}

.tree li::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
  left: -20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tree li:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

ul.tree > li:first-child::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.label-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

tree.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="tree" class="tree">
  <li *ngFor="let node of tree; let i = index">
    <div class="label-container" (click)="toggleChild(node)">
      <span *ngIf="node.children != 0">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Icons8_flat_document.svg/512px-Icons8_flat_document.svg.png"
          class="arrow-btn"
          [ngClass]="node.isOpen ? 'open-btn' : 'close-btn'"
        />
      </span>
      <span
        class="node-item"
        (click)="applyStyle(node)"
        [ngClass]="{ 'node-active': selectedItem == node.code }"
      >
        {{ node.name }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <app-tree
      *ngIf="node.showChildren"
      (selectedValue)="emitOnChildClicked($event)"
      [tree]="node.children"
    ></app-tree>
  </li>
</ul>
```

tree.mock.ts

```
export interface TreeNode {
  name: string;
  showChildren: boolean;
  children: any[];
  code: string;
}

export const NODES: TreeNode[] = [
  {
    code: 'AFRI',
    name: 'Africa',
    showChildren: false,
    children: [
      {
        code: 'ALGE',
        name: 'Algeria',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [
          {
            code: 'ARIS',
            name: 'Algeris',
            showChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            code: 'ACI2',
            name: 'Algeria child 2',
            showChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        code: 'ANGO',
        name: 'Angola',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        code: 'BENI',
        name: 'Benin',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: 'ASIA',
    name: 'Asia',
    showChildren: false,
    children: [
      {
        code: 'AFGH',
        name: 'Afghanistan',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [
          {
            code: 'KABU',
            name: 'Kabul',
            showChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        code: 'ARME',
        name: 'Armenia',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        code: 'AZER',
        name: 'Azerbaijan',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: 'EURO',
    name: 'Europe',
    showChildren: false,
    children: [
      {
        code: 'ROMA',
        name: 'Romania',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [
          {
            code: 'BUCU',
            name: 'Bucuresti',
            showChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        code: 'HUNG',
        name: 'Hungary',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
      {
        code: 'BNIN',
        name: 'Benin',
        showChildren: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    code: 'NOAM',
    name: 'North America',
    showChildren: false,
    children: [],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just add a new property to all children (selectable) elements, something like `active` and set it initially to `false`, then whenever an element is clicked: set it to `false` for all and to `true` for the selected element.

It means you'd need to add it to your `TreeNode` model:

```
active?: boolean;
```

(added here as optional, since in the code that follows you're not going to add the values *manually* to all the nodes, but programmatically).

Then, the template part of the Tree component needs only one simple change:
from `[ngClass]="{ 'node-active': selectedItem == node.code }"` to `[ngClass]="node.active ? 'node-active' : ''"` on line 14. So the css style of the children won't depend on the `selectedItem`, but on their own `active` property value.

Finnally, most changes are needed in ts/logic part of the component:

Create a method to recursively iterate over your `tree` and set all the `active` properties to `false`:

```
setAllToFalse(nodes) {
   for (let child of nodes) {
     child.active = false;
     if (child.children && Array.isArray(child.children) && child.children.length > 0) this.setAllToFalse(child.children);
   }
}
```

Add ngOnInit to the component and inside it call this recursive method to have all the nodes of that particular tree with `active` set to false initially:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.setAllToFalse(this.tree);
}
```

Change your `applyStyle` method and call `setAllToFalse` to set all the values to `false`, and after that you set this particular node's `active` to `true`:

```
applyStyle(node) {
  this.selectedItem = node.code;
  this.setAllToFalse(this.tree);
  node.active = true;
}
```

Finally, since you're also using recursion in template, you'll need to edit your `emitOnChildClicked` method too, since the `tree` in component's context can mean any sub-tree inside the 'original' tree:

```
emitOnChildClicked(node) {
  this.selectedValue.emit(node);
  this.setAllToFalse(this.tree);
  node.active = true;
}
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-example-8wuthh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree%2Ftree.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftree%2Ftree.component.html) example.

Comment: thats a great solution.. you really did put lot of effort in answering it, thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your code you have multiple instances of the `app-tree` component, and each of these has a `selectedItem`. That is the reason multiple nodes get selected.

The best way to implement communication between components is to create a service.

I would create a little service to hold the selected node code for all your `app-tree` components.

something like this should do:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

export class TreeService {
  selectedNodeCode$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
}
```

Then you adjust your `app-tree` component to no longer have the current output or the variable `selectedItem`, and replace these with

```
selectedNodeCode$ = this.treeServer.selectedNodeCode$
```

and on your `app-tree` template you change the node class logic to:

```
<span
 class="node-item"
 (click)="applyStyle(node)"
 [ngClass]="{
   'node-active': node.code == selectedNodeCode$ | async
 }"
>{{ node.name }}</span>
```

Comment: well its a good solution too, but this makes the tree component dependent on service class for creating a subject which in turn does not make the component reusable. I tried creating a subject in component but I get the same problem, but works well if I create a subject in a service